# Redigo fetches old value from Redis Docker container

Tags: docker, go, redis, redigo

I'm developing a golang web project with **Redigo** to connect to a redis **docker** container.

While the golang web application is in running state, I've changed the value of a redis key using `SET MyFlag true` in **redis-cli**. But this is not reflecting in my webapp. When `MyFlag` is fetched using `flag, err := redis.Bool(conn.Do("GET", "MyFlag"))`, it gives the old value.

But, after the webapp is **restarted**, the same command fetches the new value.

`conn` is retrieved from a redis connection pool. This is the configuration for **redis pool**

```
redisPool = &redis.Pool{
        MaxIdle:     5,
        IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
        MaxActive:   10,
        Wait:        true,
        Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
            c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", db.GetUrl())
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            password := db.GetPassword()
            if password != "" {
                if _, err := c.Do("AUTH", password); err != nil {
                    _ = c.Close()
                    return nil, err
                }
            }
            return c, nil
        },
    }
```

Is this the issue of caching in Redis/Redigo/Docker ?

Comment: Redigo does not do any caching.

Comment: Furthermore, the config of the pool is rather uninteresting. What would be more interesting is the actual code using it.

Comment: Use [redis.DialPassword](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#DialPassword) to simplify the pool dial function.  That said, this has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón for your valuable input

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg We tried it again after changing `MaxIdle: 10`. **It worked!** But I can't see any reason for that. Someone please shed some light on this behavior.

Comment: The pool configuration is not the problem.  Something else changed when max idle was changed from 5 to 10 or the change covered up some other bug.  Is it possible that the application and redis-cli connected to different servers?  Does the application handle the error returned from `redis.Bool(conn.Do("GET", "MyFlag"))` ? Perhaps `flag` is false because the command failed or the returned value is not in a format expected by `redis.Bool`.